# Batch File Adding Space to Variable

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, window

```
@ECHO OFF 
CLS

REM Start Backup
TITLE Backup

SETlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Capture the date/time(right down to the second) and then assign it to a variable
SET yy=%date:~-4%
SET dd=%date:~-7,2%
SET mm=%date:~-10,2%
SET newdate=%dd%%mm%%yy%_%Time:~0,8%
SET newdate=%newdate::=%
SET foldername=svetlana_backup_%newdate%

REM Variables
SET drive=R:
SET sevenZip=%USERPROFILE%\7z.exe

SET destination=R:\Backup

ECHO Running Backup Batch File

ECHO Please Plug in %drive%
PAUSE

ECHO %foldername%

MKDIR %destination%\%foldername%

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i IN (backuplist.txt) DO (

    SET completeSource=%%i
    SET completeDestination=%destination%\%foldername%\%%j

    ECHO Source: "!completeSource:"=!"
    ECHO Destination:"!completeDestination:"=!"

    MKDIR "!completeDestination:"=!"
    XCOPY "!completeSource:"=!" "!completeDestination:"=!" /E /F
)

REM Zip the folder using the 7z command line utility
%sevenZip% a -tzip %destination%\%foldername%.zip %destination%\%foldername%

REM Remove the unzipped backup folder
RMDIR /Q /S %destination%\%foldername%

PAUSE
EXIT
```

This is a backup batch file that I've been using for last couple of days. It worked well up until this morning. For some reason, when it creates the variable `foldername`, it contains a space in the string where there was none before. It ends up like this:

```
svetlana_backup_22092016_ 93829
```

The space between the dash and the 93829 was never there before until today for some reason. How would I remove it and prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the file-/foldername like this
    `set foldername=%foldername: =%`

This will replace all spaces with an empty string

The problem was likely caused because the test was run at a time where the hour contained just one digit. With that `%Time:~0,8%` will output the time including an extra space, as the time will be stored like this: `9:38:29` which are 7 characters and you read the last 8 ones.

Comment: That worked (give me 9 mins, SO telling me to wait before I accept an answer), but why all of a sudden did this problem turn up? It never happened until today.

Comment: Editted answer :)

Comment: replacing the space with a zero instead of deleting might be a better solution (same format for all files, so easily sortable)